# Change background color of dynamically add table row in Android

Tags: android, colors, background, row, android-tablelayout

I am trying to make a table to show my database content and I want the user of my app can select an specific row of the table. and the selected row have a different background in comparison with other row.
I want to add all thing dynamically so I have following code for my TableView (this code is a test and not connected to database yet).

```
RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
TableLayout MainLayout = new TableLayout(this);
MainLayout.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
MainLayout.setStretchAllColumns(true);   
//Create the first row and add two text views
TableRow row1 = new TableRow(this);
TextView text1 = new TextView(this);
text1.setText("Test1\n");
text1.setGravity(android.view.Gravity.CENTER);
TextView text2 = new TextView(this);
text2.setText("Test2");
text2.setGravity(android.view.Gravity.CENTER);
row1.addView(text1);
row1.addView(text2);
row1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.row_selector);
MainLayout.addView(row1);
```

and my ***row_selector.xml*** is:

```
<!-- language: xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">        
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/green" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/red" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/blue" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

and I have defined the green/red/blue color in *colors.xml* in values.
but when I run my app and click on the row, nothing changes and the background color remain transparent. I have changed the transparent to red and the color remains red even after clicking. So I know that table row is connected to the row_selector.xml properly but it does not work properly.

Why the color does not change?

Update:
I use the `$row1.setClickable(true)$` and it works properly. (It makes blue when I click on the row). so how can I have a specific color for selected row until I select another row. I mean I want to only last selected row have a different color.

Comment: use row1.setBackground(Color.RED). to change dynamically change color in class file

Comment: use row1.setClickable(true)

Comment: I use the row1.setClickable(true) and it works properly. (it makes blue when I click on the row) thank you. so how can I have a specific color for selected row until I select another row. I mean I want to selected row have a different color.

Comment: If I not mistaken, tag should be resources, not selector

Answer (score 0):

I do it myself by adding the following code:

```
row1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue);
row2.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue);
row1.setId(10001);
row2.setId(10002);

            View.OnTouchListener rowClick = new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
                {
                    if(lastRowId>0){
                        ((TableRow)findViewById(lastRowId)).setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue);
                    }
                    lastRowId = v.getId();
                    v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
                    return true;
                }
            };
            row1.setOnTouchListener(rowClick);
            row2.setOnTouchListener(rowClick);
```